# Need to copy data from one table to another with same structure

Tags: sybase

I need write a stored procedure which will be copy data from source table to destination table (both are on the same server).

We have 1.2 million records to be copied. I have used #temp table to copy all the data with some where condition (let's say 10 thousand records) and moved data by batch wise (let's say 2 thousand) from temp to destination db but temp database does not able to hold that much record and it's failing.

Some can help moving the data one to another table batch by batch without using temp db

I don't want to copy the data from csv also which is bulk import

Comment: Are the databases on the same server? Please edit your tags and define only _one_ platform, either `sql-server` or `sybase`. Is there any specific reason you can't/don't want to use a flat file for this? It's strange that a 1,200,000 row direct data copy would impact tempdb. Perhaps post the exact error

Comment: When you say "tempdb" is not able to hold the records and is failing - what exactly do you mean by that?  Are you getting any specific error messages?  10k records in a temporary table doesn't sound like a lot  ...

Comment: I suppose it depends on whether or not each record contains `varbinary(max)` columns with gigabyte sized PDFs or something. You haven't really told us much here. Why are you even moving through `tempdb`? Why not go directly from the source table to the destination table?

Comment: Please use common units 12L isn't understood by everyone.

Comment: I am getting this error ASE: Space available in segment 'logsegment' has fallen critically low in database 'tempdb'

Comment: The same thing what Dale said, use **common units**. Not local words like *lakh* or *L*.

Comment: if you're copying the entire row then why are you using an intermediate (tempdb) table? if you're running out of log space then either a) have the DBA increase the amount of log space or b) copy the data in small batches while making sure the log is dumped between batches.

Comment: how are you populating the #temp table? `insert/select` or `select/into`?

Comment: using insert/select